# Blank space before table and no captions showing

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

There is a lot of blank space on the page before a long table around the previous paragraph and the captions do not show up next to the table. 
 1. How do I get rid of this random blank space on the page before my table? 
 2. How do I add captions to this table?

The table is written in the following manner but longer:

```
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\raggedright}Xr}
    \toprule
\textbf{Label 1}& \textbf{Label 2}&\textbf{Label 3}& $N$\\
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{preparatory\\ work} &\makecell[lt]{Adding\\ information}&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
 &\makecell[lt]{organizing\\ information}&
New Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 3
\\
word &short term&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please explain for inexperienced users.

Comment: The table is a bit less than 1 page long. Not sure why my screenshot does not show.

Comment: You have no `table` environment and no `\caption` command (which has to be in a table environment).

Comment: you insert your image in table code. it should be before or after MWE (Minimal Working Example).  Please, add to your code used document class.

Comment: How do I add '''table''' environment?

Answer (score 2):

You not provide MWE, which reproduce your problem, so it is hard to tell, what is the cause of the your problem. Considering @Bernard comment, your MWE should be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]   % <--- added
\centering          % <--- added
\caption{My important table which has caption above of it} % <--- added
\label{tab:mytable} % <--- added
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\raggedright}Xr}
    \toprule
\textbf{Label 1}& \textbf{Label 2}&\textbf{Label 3}& $N$\\
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{preparatory\\ work} &\makecell[lt]{Adding\\ information}&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
 &\makecell[lt]{organizing\\ information}&
New Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 3
\\
word &short term&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

See Table \ref{tab:mytable}. \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

As you can see, proposed MWE hasn't any unusual vertical empty space. Adding `table` float environment table can float in place where is the most suitable on page.